# no suitable method found for add( )

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm working on a Java app in NetBeans for a friend. Here is the code:

```
public class ReportGenerator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
//GUI components
private JMenuBar menuBar;
private JMenu fileMenu;
private JMenuItem newItem;
    private JMenuItem openItem;
    private JMenuItem exitItem;

private ReportGeneratorSetup setup;
private ReportGeneratorProgram application;

public ReportGenerator()
{
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    fileMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
    exitItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    fileMenu.add(exitItem);
    exitItem.addActionListener(this);
    menuBar.add(fileMenu);
    this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    this.setSize(1000,1200);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);

    setup = new ReportGeneratorSetup(this);
    application = new ReportGeneratorProgram(this,setup);

    //this.add(setup);  
    this.validate();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ReportGenerator rg = new ReportGenerator();
}  
public void switchToPanel(String panel)
{
    this.getContentPane().removeAll();

    if(panel.equals("Eval"))
    {
                    application.setupComponents();
        this.getContentPane().add(application);

    }
    else if(panel.equals("Setup"))
    {
        this.getContentPane().add(setup);
    }

    this.invalidate();
    this.validate();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
{
    if(arg0.getSource() instanceof JMenuItem)
    {
        JMenuItem item = (JMenuItem)arg0.getSource();

        if(item.getText().equals("Exit"))
        {
            dispose();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

}

I am getting an error that says:

```
no suitable method found for add(reportgenerator.ReportGeneratorSetup)
    method java.awt.Container.add(java.awt.Component,java.lang.Object,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method java.awt.Container.add(java.awt.Component,java.lang.Object) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method java.awt.Container.add(java.awt.Component,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method java.awt.Container.add(java.lang.String,java.awt.Component) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method java.awt.Container.add(java.awt.Component) is not applicable
      (actual argument reportgenerator.ReportGeneratorSetup cannot be converted to java.awt.Component by method invocation conversion)
    method java.awt.Component.add(java.awt.PopupMenu) is not applicable
      (actual argument reportgenerator.ReportGeneratorSetup cannot be converted to java.awt.PopupMenu by method invocation conversion)
```

Can anyone tell me why this might be occurring? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the code for ReportGeneratorProgram? It needs to be a Component of some kind.

Comment: Well i'm getting the same error for the 'application' instance of ReportGeneratorProgram as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class `ReportGeneratorSetup` needs to be some kind of component, most likely it needs to extend `JPanel` or `JComponent`.

Comment: So you can't use the default .add() method for your own classes?

Comment: @Aaron, not unless your class inherits from the expected type, which in this case is Component. In other words, your class must extend (or implement) Component or one of its children. Your class must be "of type" Component in order to "fit" the description for the add method. It's expecting a Component, so unless you're passing it something that is a Component of some kind, it will not work.